# AngularJS multiple forms with select

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have a select tag in my page that has multiple elements and on selecting an element I show different div blocks.  Each div tag contains different input values and I have a save button that saves all the data in each of the div tags.  I am looking to validate all the entered data and I know I should be using forms.  The problem I have is that some of the forms will be hidden and if they fail validation then the user may not see the errors.  What is the best way to handle this?

```
<select class="item-select" size=10>
    <option ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" value="{{$index}}"
            ng-selected="$index == selectedItem" ng-click="ac.itemSelected($index)">
    {{item.name}}
</option>

<div ng-show="item.name == 'x'">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" ng-model="item.options.p" step="0.1" />%
</div>
<div ng-show="item.name == 'y'">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="100" ng-model="item.options.p" step="0.1" />%
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if it is the best solution - you could use ng-if instead of ng-show. ng-show just hide the element (display: none). The ng-if deletes whole element from DOM. If you want to stay with ng-show - after item selection change model variables in controller so it will always validate.

Comment: You should wrap everything inside a form. If you need to validate all data before save, you need only one form and hide/show any input inside it. Then you are able to iterate over any form error. I can provide an answer telling you how to use form validation in this case if you don't know about it.

Comment: If I wrap everything inside a form and there is a validation error on one of the hidden div tags then I'd have to jump around the select options and show/hide different data, which would be confusing for the user.